# Starting Ipython with Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, ipython

I have my ipthon startup script as follows

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 \
--notebook-dir='/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/' \
--ip='*' --no-browser" pyspark
```

It runs fine for older Spark. But when I switch to Spark2, I get the following error:

IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed in Spark 2.0+. Remove these from the environment and set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS instead.

It is not clear what command I should replace it with. Can someone help?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: 'jupyter notebook' starts it.

Answer (score 8):

For Spark < 2.0 the command to start `pyspark` with IPython was:

`IPYTHON=1 pyspark`

The equivalent updated command for Spark >= 2.0 is:

`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark`

according to [Spark's source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L27-L31).

Comment: `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython` works for me. I use **spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7**

Comment: it's doing the same thing but for your whole shell session

Comment: @runitao 

`[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand \`ipython notebook\` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use \`jupyter notebook\`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
[I 12:43:30.567 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/cloudera
[I 12:43:30.567 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels`

I dont understand how it is loading Jupyter notebook instead of ipython CLI with these options. Any idea?

Comment: @DeepakJanyavula I didn't see this warning before. Maybe you can add 'set -x` in your pyspark file to debug.