# Unable to Launch Jupyter Notebook for pyspark OSX: IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed in Spark 2.0+

Tags: macos, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have downloaded : spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

In my `~/.bash_profile` I have following:

```
export PATH="/Users/spandan.chakraborty/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON='jupyter'

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'

alias snote='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

But when ever I am trying to Launch Jupyter notebook with the command alias : snote I am getting following error:

> Error in pyspark startup:
>
> IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed in Spark 2.0+. Remove these from
>   the environment and set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and
>   PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS instead.

I have referred to similar issue as  posted in [Starting Ipython with Spark 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658694/starting-ipython-with-spark-2)

but with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, (I am running on my MAC)

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPAK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" /Users/abhishekdutta/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Following has solved the Issue:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```